# How to create multiple nested lists in a sidebar that scrolls as one?

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list, disclosuregroup

I am trying to create a sidebar that contains multiple `DisclosureGroup`s where some of them contain a nested list. The whole sidebar when fully expanded will be longer than the screen, so it needs to scroll.

My test code for macOS looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

class MenuItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text : String
    var children : [MenuItem]? = [MenuItem]()
    
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var menuItems = [MenuItem]()
    
    init() {
        for itemText in ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"] {
            menuItems.append(MenuItem(text: itemText))
        }
        for item in menuItems {
            for childText in ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"] {
                item.children?.append(MenuItem(text: childText))
            }
        }
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            DisclosureGroup("Section 1") {
                List(menuItems, children: \.children) { item in
                    Text(item.text)
                }            }
            DisclosureGroup("Section 2") {
                Text("Some other stuff")
            }
            DisclosureGroup("Section 3") {
                List(menuItems, children: \.children) { item in
                    Text(item.text)
                }.frame(minHeight: 300)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that Section 2 expands as expected, while section 1 does not expand at all. I can make a nested list show up by giving it a fixed frame (like in section 3), but then I get a scrolling list within a scrolling sidebar and the frame does not adjust to the size of the expanded nested list.

My aim is to have one big scrolling sidebar with three `DisclosureGroup`s that collapses, expands and scrolls as one unit.

Comment: Why not have one List instead of the scroll view

Comment: @loremipsum Doesn't work. Section 1 does not expand and section 3 lives in its own scrollview.